# Passing additional arguments through function handle in Matlab

Tags: function, matlab, optimization, handle

I have a function to optimize, say Function, in Matlab. This function depends on variables (say x) over which I want to optimize and one parameter (say, Q) which does not need to be optimized.Hence, the function Function(x,Q). In other words, I have an array of values for Q and want to find optimal x values for each Q. However, I cannot find a way how to pass those Q values when using function handle @Function in optimization function.

So, my question is how to pass those Q values when using function handle in optimization functions, for example fmincon(@Function,x0,A,b)?

Comment: Does `fmincon(@Function,x0,Q,A,b)` work?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin  No, It does not work. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using anonymous function:

```
x = cell( 1, numel(Q) );
for qi = 1:numel( Q )
   x{qi} = fmincon( @(x) Function(x, Q(qi)), A, b );
end
```

Answer (score 4):

As described in MATLAB documentation, there are actually 3 solutions for this problem:

1. **Anonymous Functions**
   which is described in the [Shai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14943113/1714410) of this post.
2. **Nested Functions**:
   in this approach the outer function accepts all arguments, and the inner function only accepts parameters that optimization takes place on them. 
   this is an example taken from MATLAB documentation:

   `function [x,fval] =  runnested(a,b,c,x0)
      [x,fval] = fminunc(@nestedfun,x0);
      % Nested function that computes the objective function
      function y = nestedfun(x)
         y = (a - b*x(1)^2 + x(1)^4/3)*x(1)^2 + x(1)x(2) +...
             (-c + cx(2)^2)*x(2)^2;
      end
   end`
3. **Global Variables**
   in this approach you should define the parameters that are needed in objective function as `global` in workspace, and use them in objective function with declaring them as global.
   here is an example again from MATLAB documentation:

   - Defining objective function:

     `function y = globalfun(x)
     global a b c
     y = (a - b*x(1)^2 + x(1)^4/3)*x(1)^2 + x(1)x(2) + ...
     (-c + cx(2)^2)*x(2)^2;
     end`
   - Optimization:

     `global a b c;
     a = 4; b = 2.1; c = 4; % Assign parameter values
     x0 = [0.5,0.5];
     [x,fval] = fminunc(@globalfun,x0)`

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do the following:

```
x = fmincon(fun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon,options,Q)
```

which will pass Q along to `fun(x,Q)`!